# Should I walk or step on your bed to get to other side?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

What English term do you use in this context?

> "When you are getting to the other side of your room, but you got no choice to **walk / step** on your bed."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, *climbing* does work in this context, but there is another way to tell. Tiny rooms with large beds are nothing but discomfort to the tourists and that's why, you see a lot of complaints made by the visitors visiting hotels worldwide.

Two such examples I came across on TripAdvisor where the visitors had to [***walk over the bed***](https://www.tripadvisor.in/ShowUserReviews-g186346-d192673-r262210877-Ibis_York_Centre-York_North_Yorkshire_England.html) to go to the other side of the room. In fact, one of them posted [a photo of it](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g226906-d227986-i86727498-Holiday_Inn_Helsinki_Vantaa_Airport-Vantaa_Uusimaa.html) where the arrangement of other furniture is such that it's difficult to pass by the bed. The **exact** case that you described here.

Answer (score 3):

I would *climb over* the bed.

> I had to **climb over** the bed to get to the window. (Because there is no room to walk around the bed.)

An idiomatic usage as far as I know, but see [*climb*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/climb):

> 3. to move (*down, over, along*, etc.), using the hands and feet

Comment: I think that "climb over to get to the window" talks about when the window is higher and it's needed to climb on something to get there, but the question here is about when having for example a small room in which the bed separates the two parts of this room, and in order to get to the second part you should step on it  or "cross" it like a bridge.

Comment: I meant that the window is on the other side of the room, and you cannot walk around the bed.

Comment: So even in case that you have to 'cross' the bed, you'll still say "climb over". Yes?

Comment: Yes. Think of it as on the floor, on the bed, then on the floor on the other side. The bed is higher than the floor... (AmE disclaimer, if it matters.)

Comment: Yes, I got you. You basically says that the bed in this context is a sort of a small mountain.:) Thank you for the explanation

Comment: I think this answer is a bit off according to my question, BUT is absolutely correct when in **different circumstance** in a way that you use the bed as a **'stool'** just to reach things such as a higher place when the bed **blocks the path**, or due to snug space of your room.